# Preventing React from clearing dropdown menus housed in a child component after a re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, state, dropdown

I'm building a search component. I have an API endpoint to which I can add searchParams depending on what dropdown the user chooses. It also makes separate call to find out what dropdown content will include.

So a user could type in "Audi" and then the dropdowns would be pre-filled with various options like "Engine Type" - but they're optional.

The result is a response from an API containing an array of all matching vehicles. Pretty simple.

What's interesting is that the dropdowns live in their own `<AdvancedDropdowns>` component. On page load, the parent `<Search />` which houses ` passes down the recently retrieved options, populating them upon initial render. In other words, now the dropdowns have "V4, V8" etc as options for, say, Engine dropdown.

I'm passing a handler to `<AdvancedDropdowns />` so that when a user picks, say, V8 as a dropdown option, I need to do another call in real-time to the original API point except the url looks more like this: `api.com/?query=audi&engine=v4`. This will re-render the list but it will also re-render the child `<AdvancedDropdowns />` component and thus clear out the selections.

The problem is that if they make even one selection, the handler will run, the now modified URL will be called, and as the list re-renders it's impossible to select more than one dropdown at a time because by selecting even one, the re-render clears out the list.

I've been thinking about using the re-render as an opportunity to pass the recorded selections back to the dropdown and let it set its defaults to what was already selected as it's being re-rendered but it seems a little strange.

Here's the behavior I'd like to see:

- User types something in the search box? Hit the API and show a new list
- User types something in, gets new list, then chooses a dropdown? Hit the API and get another list
- User types something in, gets new list, chooses *two* dropdowns? Hit the API once per dropdown (three times total at this point)

The idea is to feel as responsive of a "filter" as possible but I'm struggling since re-rendering clears out the previous dropdown selections.

Hope that makes sense.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you're setting some state or running some side effect when that url changes.

Are you setting a piece of state that the `<AdvancedDropdowns />`s are using? If so, any of them that are using any piece of the state(s) that change will re-render when changed/set.

I'd recommend using multiple `useState()`s, one for each drop down, so when you send the api call and update the next `<AdvancedDropdowns />` by setting state, it won't effect any other drop downs.

Comment: I thought about that. At the moment I'm sending "back" a prop that has updated state and that becomes the "initialValue" of a dropdown element (it's part of a UI library so it's not exactly a <select>) Are you suggesting that each dropdown has a piece of state at the parent level and then then pass those down as initial values? All the fetching is happening at the parent level and so I need to get the dropdown values OUT somehow but I'm scratching my head at the optimal way of doing it

Comment: @dsp_099 yes, basically you’ll use the state variable as the value/initialValue, then get the value “out” by using that same state’s setter function in the `onChange`.

Comment: If I type anything in the responsive input box in the parent, it will re-render and thus wipe out any previous selections of the dropdowns. Selecting something from the dropdown will do the exact same thing. I want the values the user selected to be kept so they can essentially toggle search options on and off and have the list re-render without losing the dropdown selections. I've sort of solved it - I keep track of what the dropdown selection is at the parent level, then when a re-render happens, I pass the saved values to the dropdowns and use those values as initial.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if the dropdowns "lived" in the parent instead of their own component and maintained their state there, in which case I could just bind the useState() entries as the initial values but I have this extra added step of having them in a separate component. I hope that makes sense.